# How its possible to use variable using javascript (Selenium webdriver)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I'm beginner with javascript because I'm still working with Java selenium webdriver.

Now I need to use `javascript`, but I cannot find answers how it's possible to use variable using javascript between two files.

It means `page1.js` contains element1 and page2.js contains element2 (i have two different front-end page).

For example, for better understanding (only one front-end page):

```
// Store and compare values using JAVA into one file (front-end page).

    webelement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("notearea"));
    webelement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="sidebar"]
/div...  "));

    String actual = element1.getText();
    String expected = element2.getText();
    System.out.println(actual);
    System.out.println(expected);

 if(expected.equals(actual)){
            System.out.println("Pass");
        }
            else {
                System.out.println("Fail");
            }
```

My question is:

How it's possible to use this example, using javascript webdriver if element1 is on a different page?

Thank you very much for every answer.

Comment: Are the two pages displayed in the same browser in different tabs or completely different browsers (or (i)frames)? There is plenty of information about browser data-store and resource sharing if the two pages are in the same browser. You probably need a back-end solution to share the value otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, Element1 is on Dashboard page and element2 is displayed by clicking on the button Next - another page contains the list of records (the same window - the same browser and iframe but diffrent web page and also another java file js).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your element1 is not inside a function and that your file is load in the correct order.

```
<script src="page1.js"><script> //declare var element1=1 here
<script src="page2.js"><script> // you can access element1 from here.
```